# "Pow is installed" shows up on all my sites now

Tags: ruby, macos, rack-pow

I installed Pow with RVM for a rails app I'm working on.  It's fine.  It's the other sites that now all say "Pow is installed". I'm sure it's a simple setting, but I'm not able to find it.  Has anyone run into this before?

I'm running MAMP on Snow Leopard.

Comment: How did you install it using RVM? RVM installs Ruby instances. `rvm list known` is the list of things that RVM can install.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pow will alter your DNS resolution to have all domains that end in .dev or .test be routed to the local machine (to hit pow).

If you want to use MAMP as well as POW you'll need to turn off pow temporarily for it to be useable (Or you could change the MAMP settings use another port besides 80).

To turn off pow i'd recommend installing the `powder` gem:

```
gem install powder

powder down
```

You could also use pow to serve up static sites, you'll just need a blank config.ru and a public folder to get going. More info in the pow manual here: http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.4

Answer (score 4):

You can use `curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh`

Especially if you don't want to install anything else immediately.